# How to get year key array insert month key array nested array such as

Tags: php, arrays

We are create todo task. we added list item to add all todo in one array. in front side we need to collected in one array. now we need to create separate array such year group. year group insert month data. my code is below.

This is my PHP array code.

```
array(

    array(

        'title' => 'Test 2019',
        'todo_title' => 'Test 2019',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1548892800',
        'todo_date' => 'January 31, 2019',
        'todo_year' => '2019',
        'todo_month' => '1',
        'todo_unique_id' => '819097135',
        'todo_status' => '0',
    ),
    array(

        'title' => 'Test new data',
        'todo_title' => 'Test new data',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1550620800',
        'todo_date' => 'February 20, 2019',
        'todo_year' => '2019',
        'todo_month' => '2',
        'todo_unique_id' => '1833135764',
        'todo_status' => '0',
    ),
    array(

        'title' => 'Loriem ipsum',
        'todo_title' => 'Loriem ipsum',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1552953600',
        'todo_date' => 'March 19, 2019',
        'todo_year' => '2019',
        'todo_month' => '3',
        'todo_unique_id' => '1501977081',
        'todo_status' => '0',
    ),
    array(

        'title' => 'asdfasf',
        'todo_title' => 'asdfasf',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1579910400',
        'todo_date' => 'January 25, 2020',
        'todo_year' => '2020',
        'todo_month' => '1',
        'todo_status' => '1',
        'todo_unique_id' => '1573546118',
    ),
    array(

        'title' => 'Hello world',
        'todo_title' => 'Hello world',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1580428800',
        'todo_date' => 'January 31, 2020',
        'todo_year' => '2020',
        'todo_month' => '1',
        'todo_status' => '1',
        'todo_unique_id' => '314611084',
    ),
    array(

        'title' => 'Test',
        'todo_title' => 'Test',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1582156800',
        'todo_date' => 'February 20, 2020',
        'todo_year' => '2020',
        'todo_month' => '2',
        'todo_unique_id' => '184291872',
        'todo_status' => '0',
    ),
    array(

        'title' => 'Hello world',
        'todo_title' => 'Hello world',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1583452800',
        'todo_date' => 'March 6, 2020',
        'todo_year' => '2020',
        'todo_month' => '3',
        'todo_status' => '1',
        'todo_unique_id' => '383849492',
    )
)
```

How can i retrieve list of array to collected as year array push month array code is below.

```
array(

  '2019'  => array(

      '1'   => array(

            array(

                'title' => 'Test 2019',
                'todo_title' => 'Test 2019',
                'todo_strtotime' => '1548892800',
                'todo_date' => 'January 31, 2019',
                'todo_year' => '2019',
                'todo_month' => '1',
                'todo_unique_id' => '819097135',
                'todo_status' => '0',
            ),
      ),
      '2'   => array(

              array(

                  'title' => 'Test new data',
                  'todo_title' => 'Test new data',
                  'todo_strtotime' => '1550620800',
                  'todo_date' => 'February 20, 2019',
                  'todo_year' => '2019',
                  'todo_month' => '2',
                  'todo_unique_id' => '1833135764',
                  'todo_status' => '0',
              ),
      ),
      '3'   => array(

              array(

                  'title' => 'Loriem ipsum',
                  'todo_title' => 'Loriem ipsum',
                  'todo_strtotime' => '1552953600',
                  'todo_date' => 'March 19, 2019',
                  'todo_year' => '2019',
                  'todo_month' => '3',
                  'todo_unique_id' => '1501977081',
                  'todo_status' => '0',
              ),
      ),
  ),

  '2020'  => array(

      '1'   => array(

              array(

                  'title' => 'asdfasf',
                  'todo_title' => 'asdfasf',
                  'todo_strtotime' => '1579910400',
                  'todo_date' => 'January 25, 2020',
                  'todo_year' => '2020',
                  'todo_month' => '1',
                  'todo_status' => '1',
                  'todo_unique_id' => '1573546118',
              ),
      ),
      '2'   => array(

              array(

                  'title' => 'Test',
                  'todo_title' => 'Test',
                  'todo_strtotime' => '1582156800',
                  'todo_date' => 'February 20, 2020',
                  'todo_year' => '2020',
                  'todo_month' => '2',
                  'todo_unique_id' => '184291872',
                  'todo_status' => '0',
              ),

      ),
      '3'   => array(

              array(

                  'title' => 'Hello world',
                  'todo_title' => 'Hello world',
                  'todo_strtotime' => '1583452800',
                  'todo_date' => 'March 6, 2020',
                  'todo_year' => '2020',
                  'todo_month' => '3',
                  'todo_status' => '1',
                  'todo_unique_id' => '383849492',
              )
      ),
  )
)
```

How can i retrive like this code in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with simple foreach

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
   $newarray[$value['todo_year']][] = $value;
}
print_r($newarray);
```

Comment: you forgot `[` and `]` around `[$value]['todo_year']`, it should be `$newarray[$value['todo_year']][]`

Comment: Please mark this an answer if it does help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Full Example

```
<?php

$todo_data = array(

    array(

        'title' => 'Test 2019',
        'todo_title' => 'Test 2019',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1548892800',
        'todo_date' => 'January 31, 2019',
        'todo_year' => '2019',
        'todo_month' => '1',
        'todo_unique_id' => '819097135',
        'todo_status' => '0',
    ),
    array(

        'title' => 'Test new data',
        'todo_title' => 'Test new data',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1550620800',
        'todo_date' => 'February 20, 2019',
        'todo_year' => '2019',
        'todo_month' => '2',
        'todo_unique_id' => '1833135764',
        'todo_status' => '0',
    ),
    array(

        'title' => 'Loriem ipsum',
        'todo_title' => 'Loriem ipsum',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1552953600',
        'todo_date' => 'March 19, 2019',
        'todo_year' => '2019',
        'todo_month' => '3',
        'todo_unique_id' => '1501977081',
        'todo_status' => '0',
    ),
    array(

        'title' => 'asdfasf',
        'todo_title' => 'asdfasf',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1579910400',
        'todo_date' => 'January 25, 2020',
        'todo_year' => '2020',
        'todo_month' => '1',
        'todo_status' => '1',
        'todo_unique_id' => '1573546118',
    ),
    array(

        'title' => 'Hello world',
        'todo_title' => 'Hello world',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1580428800',
        'todo_date' => 'January 31, 2020',
        'todo_year' => '2020',
        'todo_month' => '1',
        'todo_status' => '1',
        'todo_unique_id' => '314611084',
    ),
    array(

        'title' => 'Test',
        'todo_title' => 'Test',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1582156800',
        'todo_date' => 'February 20, 2020',
        'todo_year' => '2020',
        'todo_month' => '2',
        'todo_unique_id' => '184291872',
        'todo_status' => '0',
    ),
    array(

        'title' => 'Hello world',
        'todo_title' => 'Hello world',
        'todo_strtotime' => '1583452800',
        'todo_date' => 'March 6, 2020',
        'todo_year' => '2020',
        'todo_month' => '3',
        'todo_status' => '1',
        'todo_unique_id' => '383849492',
    )
);


$new_todo_data = [];
foreach ($todo_data as $item){
    $new_todo_data[$item['todo_year']][] = $item;
}
print_r($new_todo_data);
```

Comment: repeating the question's array data does not make it a _Full_ er answer..., just less legible, it is not necessary.